# How to set null value to an existing attribute on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

**Scenario:**
I have an entity with a (nullable) FK `Id` that it's not required anymore.

**Problem:**
When I update this entity on the context, setting `NULL` to the FK, after the `SaveChanges()` the value is not persisted on the db.

Any ideas?

**Edit #1:**
After the `SaveChanges`, I checked the base and continues the old value, and if I change to other value works fine.

**Class:**

```
public class Account
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? PlanId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    #region Navigations Properties

    public virtual Plan Plan { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

**Usage:** (Problem)

```
Account ent = Context.Set<Account>().AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = id);
ent.PlanId = null;
Context.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit [PROBLEM SOLVED]**

It was necessary to send an array with the fields that would get null as the new value.

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate, List<string> updateNullFields)
{
    DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
    foreach (var item in updateNullFields)
    {
        Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).Property(item).IsModified = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: without savechange any change won't affect the db

Comment: Did you just make the FK nullable in your class without changing the database?

Comment: I'll update the post to suply more information.

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: EF6, having exactly the same problem, cannot understand why. Interesting, if before saving the changes I assign null to the property in the Immediate Window, the property correctly sets to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you most likely did not update the database itself. 
Once you update the database using this code:

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] ALTER COLUMN [fk_column] [datatype] NULL
```

Run 'Update Model from Database' on the .edmx file.
[image]

Make sure this Nullable = true
[image]

Comment: I'm using Migration to maintain the DB, and the FK already is nullable... the problem it's on EF that not persist the null value on the db after the attribute has any non-null value.

Comment: Is this on a save or edit action? You should check the entity state to make sure the object is modified before inserting/updating it.

Comment: I've to pass these fields that i want to force the null value, to set it as `IsModified = true;` after i Attach.

`
            DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            foreach (var item in updateNullFields)
            {
                Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).Property(item).IsModified = true;
            }
`